# java.net.BindException: Permission denied when starting Wiser SMTP Server

Tags: java, macos, permissions, smtp

I'm on Mac using Java and try to start Wiser SMTP server within a test, but keep getting:

```
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
```

I use the following Wiser initialisation:

```
import org.subethamail.wiser.Wiser;

public void start() {
    wiser.start();
  }
```

There were suggestions on the internet to run it as a root user, which I'm not sure is applicable here...

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users port numbers up to 1024 are reserved for root users. Initialise Wiser by assigning a port number over 1024 at first:

```
public void start() {
    wiser.setPort(1025);
    wiser.start();
  }
```